# Visual Studio 2017 stops working and shows many console windows after opening

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I open VS2017 it opens and then shows 10-20 command prompt windows then it stops working and responding..

I used to use it for C++, but now, I use it with unity's C# scripts.
It was working until yesterday when I opened it and found it like this.
I didn't play with the settings or the files of the program....

[An Image for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce3TU.png)

Comment: It sounds like your installation may be corrupted.  Have you tried uninstalling, and then reinstalling VS2017?

Comment: Not since I installed it first time (months ago) @JimFell but the problem is new

Comment: Please tell us the name of the executable that is running in each of these terminal windows.

Comment: Would you, please clarify what do you mean? @spender

Comment: VS is spawning programs. They open in console windows. You should find out which program is running in these windows. There will probably be 10-20 similar entries in task manager that you could look at.

Comment: @MuhammadNihad If the name can't be read from the title bar in the popup windows you are getting, you can use the Process Explorer utility from Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: oh, it is gServiceHub.Host.Node.x86.exe *32   or D:\Program Files 2\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\ServiceHub\Hosts\ServiceHub.Host.Node.x86\gServiceHub.Host.Node.x86.exe

Answer (score 2):

Is your OS installed on C disk?
if your answer is yes,sometimes the visual studio can give such errors ;install your visual studio on c disk

Comment: "Is it on c drive? Yes? Install it on c drive" doesn't make sense.

Comment: My OS is installed on C but Visual Studio is not, it is installed on D instead, but -as you know- some files will be written on C anyway.... So do you mean that I have to remove and reinstall Visual studio on C?!

Comment: @MuhammadNihad That'd probably be a good idea, to reinstall it on C.  Most IDEs I've worked with are not very friendly running on alternate drives.

Comment: @MuhammadNihad yes

Comment: @spender doesn't make sense for you but i had too much problems when vs installed on different disk